# a tad restless meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

in the Woody Allen movie - Annie Hall, after Deane sung, Woody said 
So the audience was a tad restless.
Diane “ What do you mean, a tad restless?

restless in this context is constant activity, however I am not sure about tad meaning searching in the web 
tad - a small amount - so please advise what is the meaning in this context

that the audience was in a small amount not active ?

Comment: How much have you researched already?  Given **[tad](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tad)** and **[restless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restless)**, what more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restless, the dictionary says "constantly moving" but I think **unable to sit still** or **bored and distracted** may be better definitions.

So being "a tad restless" means the audience is getting a little bit bored, they are making noise, coughing, moving in their seats, checking their watches, etc. Restless in this case is the opposite of engaged and paying attention to the play.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'tad' is British colloquialism for 'a small amount', or 'very little' or 'minuscule'.